# How do I project an object into a list using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I find myself always needing to thin out objects before sending them over the wire.

**Background:**

`Position` is a heavy contender, which was generated by LINQ to SQL based off my table.  It stores the motherlode of data.

`SPosition` is a lightweight object, which stores *only* my latitude and longitide.

**Code:**

```
 List<SPosition> spositions = new List<SPosition>();
 foreach (var position in positions)  // positions = List<Position>
 {
    SPosition spos = new SPosition { latitude = position.Latitude, longitude = position.Longitude };
    spositions.Add(spos);
 }

 return spositions.SerializeToJson<List<SPosition>>();
```

How can I use some LINQ magic to clean this up a bit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var spositions = positions.Select(
                     position => new SPosition
                         {
                             latitude = position.Latitude,
                             longitude = position.Longitude
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: append ".ToList()" to the end to return a List<SPosition> instead of an IEnumerable<SPosition>

Answer (score 6):

```
return positions
    .Select(x => new SPosition 
    { 
        latitude = x.Latitude, 
        longitude = x.Longitude 
    })
    .ToList()
    .SerializeToJson<List<SPosition>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
positions.ForEach((p) => {spositions.Add({new SPosition { latitude = p.Latitude, longitude = p.Longitude };      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (from p in positions
        select new SPosition 
        {
            latitude = p.Latitude,
            longitude = p.Longitude
        }).ToList().SerializeToJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

First thought:

```
 return positions.Select(p => new SPosition 
        { 
            latitude = p.Latitude, 
            longitude = p.Longitude 
        }).ToList().SerializeToJson<List<SPosition>>();
```

Haven't had a chance to test the code, but I think it'll work.